# Classload accessing with PHP - is it possible to load the same class from 2 different resources?

Tags: php, joomla

I am just wondering, I actually decided to go down a different route.
I create this file A

`C:\somefolder\templates\mytemplate\joomlaoverwrites\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php`

which overwrites a joomla library file:

`C:\somefolder\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php`

I use the overwrite by using

`require_once(__DIR__ . '/joomlaoverwrites/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');`
in my index.php of my template

This actually works.

What I now want to do is use my file just as a wrapper class, and sneak my changes into it before returning the answer. E.g.:

```
    public function fetchHead($document)
{

    $joomlasOriginalHead = callOriginalFunctionFetchHeadFromTheJoomlaImplementation();
    //do my changes to joomlas original answer and return that
}
```

E.g. from that overwrite, I want to call the original file. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You class needs to extend the parent class, and then you can access all parent class methods with $this->methodName() or parent::methodName().

Comment: right why didn't i think of that